# How to get PlannerImage from BufferedImage in java?

Tags: java, netbeans, platform

I m making Desktop App for dentist in netbeans platform in java swing. now i just finishied GUI of My App and i m Doing ImageProcessing. in this process i want PlannerImage Object from BufferedImage.so how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

The `Java Adavanced Imaging` lib has a method `javax.media.jai.PlanarImage.getGraphics()` which you could use to write your Image to: `.drawImage(.....)`;

[JAI](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai-apidocs/javax/media/jai/PlanarImage.html#getGraphics%28%29)